# Find element in a list matching a pattern (using wildcards)

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering, searching

Somehow, I did not manage to find anything related to that.
Suppose, in my `Global` list of variables, I would like to make a search such that I obtain all the elements in the list which start with `func`. Trying the naive choice of

```
Cases[Names["Global`*"], func_]
```

does not work, however I cannot see how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`PatternTest (?)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)  with [`StringMatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html)

```
Cases[Names["Global`*"], _?(StringMatchQ["func*"])]
```

or with [`StringStartsQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringStartsQ.html)

```
Cases[Names["Global`*"], _?(StringStartsQ["func"]) ]
```

Note the redundant-looking `(..)` after `?`.

Alternatively, you can use [`Condition (/;)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)

```
Cases[Names["Global`*"], x_ /; StringMatchQ[ x, "func*"] ]
Cases[Names["Global`*"], x_/;StringStartsQ[ x, "func"] ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Or, if you are not wedded to `Cases` and patterns, you could use `Select` and a predicate, something like

```
Select[Names["Global`*"], StringStartsQ["func"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply include the pattern in `Names`?

```
In[1]:= Names["System`Plot*"]

Out[1]= {"Plot", "Plot3D", "Plot3Matrix", "PlotDivision", \
"PlotJoined", "PlotLabel", "PlotLabels", "PlotLayout", "PlotLegends", \
"PlotMarkers", "PlotPoints", "PlotRange", "PlotRangeClipping", \
"PlotRangeClipPlanesStyle", "PlotRangePadding", "PlotRegion", \
"PlotStyle", "PlotTheme"}
```